# What is the difference between Function.prototype.call() and Function.prototype.bind()?

Tags: javascript

I went throught the MDN documentation, but I didn't really understand the difference between call() and bind(). They both seem to do the same thing - change the context of `this` inside a function. So what really is the difference between them? And which should be used when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`call` actually calls the function with the specified context while `bind` returns a new function which will use the specified context when called. An example of using `bind` would be setting an event listener, usually the context would be set to the object that triggered the event. You can use bind to create a function which uses your own context and pass it as the listener function.